# Posting Schema.Types.ObjectId arrays to MongoDB

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

How can I post an array of Schema.Types.ObjectId (s) to MongoDB? I'm trying to create User Groups, which is a group of the 'User' Model e.g.

```
var UserGroup = new Schema({
    users: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }]
});
```

New UserGroup Function

```
module.exports.create = function(request, response) {
    var group = new UserGroup({
        users = request.body.users
    });

    group.save(function(error) {
        if(error) { throw error; } else { response.send('Group Created Successfully.');
    });
};
```

I'm currently using Postman to test the functionality, how exactly should the data be posted?

As a Javascript array i.e `['A_USER_ID', 'A_USER_ID']` ?

Thanks!

Comment: You have not defined an array in the schema. It should instead be `"user": [{ "type": Schema.Types.ObjectID, "ref": "User" }]`. Note the `[]` around it. And make sure you have a body parser set that is correcty converting the array data you are sending.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Apologies, the above isn't the actual code from my application, I quickly wrote that when I was creating the post, the actual code is an array. `And make sure you have a body parser set that is correcty converting the array data you are sending.` - How exactly would I do that? Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Answer

I was using the older syntax of the select() function, and therefore was passing invalid parameters to the $push function. When sending the request, I simply pass the `ObjectIds` as `id,id,id` and once they get to the server, simply put it into an array using `var my_array = request.body.users.split(',');` and then push it to the database using the following:

`$push: { users: { $each: my_array } }`

I hope this was helpful, the documentation isn't particularly clear on this matter.